# belongs_to with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using Rails 2.3.11.

```
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :modelb
  has_one :modelc, :through => :modelb
end

class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :modelc
end

class ModelC < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :modelb
end

a = ModelA.find(x)
a.modelc # is nil (why??)
a.modelb.modelc # works fine
```

Is there a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the Issue,

```
inst_modelb = Factory(:modelb, :modelc => Factory(:modelc))
a=Factory(:modela, :modelb => inst_modelb)
a.modelc # was nil

#this worked
a.reload
a.modelc
```

Its seemed to be a caching issue. Cant fully reason it though

Comment: Why didn't you mention this code in your question? This is completely different code than your question.

Comment: Why is it a different question ? I have asked a similar one earlier "a.modelc # is nil (why??)"